# Prevent month/year selection from changing the date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ and am trying to change a specific behavior:  When you change from the view where you can pick a day to the view where you can pick a month (or the view where you can pick a year), when you pick a month (or a year), the date changes to the first of that month (or year).  I don't want that to trigger the `changeDate` event.

Alternatively, if there were a way to disable the month/year view, that would probably work as well.

I don't see anything in the documentation for this datepicker to indicate that this is possible, but I'm hoping that it is.

**FOLLOWUP:**

I opened `bootstrap-datepicker.js` and commented out lines 285-292, which seemed to work for the above.

```
//if (this.viewMode !== 0) {
//  this.date = new Date(this.viewDate);
//  this.element.trigger({
//      type: 'changeDate',
//      date: this.date,
//      viewMode: DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].clsName
//  });
//}
```

However, how do I prevent `onRender` in the same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same `bootstrap-datepicker.js` file, I modified line 210 from this:

```
clsName = this.onRender(prevMonth);
```

To this:

```
clsName = (this.viewMode == 0) ? this.onRender(prevMonth) : '';
```

Now, onRender is only called when the current `viewMode` is `0` (days).